# Easy AJAX, MySQL, and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I’m trying to get [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) to work. Here is my HTML as familyguy.html.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else { 
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
  <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
  <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
  <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And [here](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xucajhs6) is my php code getuser.php.

I’ve created the stuff_data database and populated it with 4 rows. My dropdown list does nothing. Please help.

Thanks.

Neo

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser's debugging console?  When you use the browser's script debugger, is the function invoked at all?  If so, what happens when you step through the execution of that function?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Is PHP error reporting turned on?  Are there any errors in the PHP logs?  If the PHP code is being successfully invoked by this operation, what happens when you debug that PHP code?  "Does nothing" is a non-starter.  This is an opportunity to debug your code.

Comment: are you sure you have the database at the specified address? or have you created it locally on your machine?

Comment: `getuser.php` shouldn't return an entire HTML page. It should just return the HTML that you want to show in `txtHint`.

Comment: You must post all your (relevant) code here, making sure it forms a [mre] of your issue, without any cutter.  Questions which post code in external links or as picture are eligible to be closed as off topic. See also [ask].

Comment: I’m in a psych ward and am only allowed a tablet that can’t install apps. The code snippet editor doesn’t support touch devices now. It was supported an hour ago. Please click my link to view my PHP code.

Comment: You don't need the code snippet editor, you can post code from any mobile device, I do it all the time. Start the code section with ``` to format it, and end it the same.  The rules of the site apply to every question regardless of who posts them or where from. Remember  we're not a helpdesk...the purpose here is to create useful questions to exist for the long term. That goal is undermined when key parts of the question exist only on other sites which may cease to function, or the content may be removed or changed. That is the reason for this restriction. See the [help/on-topic] for more info

Comment: The code snippet editor gives no benefit for php code anyway, it's only useful where you're trying to demo html/javascript which can be executed within the browser. So even if you were able to access the snippet editor it wouldn't be appropriate to use it for this task, you would always just format the code as I've described above

Answer (score 1):

I changed the host field to localhost and this solved the problem.